# Basic Python Hello World Program Syntax Error

Tags: python, linux, centos, python-idle

I am not that really new in Programming but in Python I am really a newbie, and so when I started learning Python from the tutorials they encouraged me to use the IDLE editor for Python. And so as a newbie I had this weird Hello World problem.

[image]

as you can see i use Python 2.6.6 in Linux(CentOS 6.2)

and I tried almost all the possible syntaxes printing the simple HELLOWORLD provided in the documentation of python 2.6 and the new python 3

I tried printing contants like this

```
print 1 + 1
```

and it work with an output

```
>>> 2
```

I want to know how can i print this simple `HELLOWORLD`

Comment: I'm guessing you're using non-ASCII quote characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure that you are really using straight quotes. Some programs/systems automatically replace them with curly quotes.

Here try copy pasting this and running it:

```
print "hello"
```

If this turn's out to be an issue then you might want to ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ how to disable such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're typing different double-quotes than what Python requires. Maybe your IME has "smart quotes" turned on or something? Anyway, you could try:

```
print 'hello world'
```

using single quotes (really, the apostrophe character) as an alternative. If you can't make that work, then copy and paste what I've written in this answer and that should work.

Here's one with double quotes for you to copy too:

```
print "hello world"
```

Comment: yeah! i thought i getting to some weird problem already. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes, not fancy quotes or diaereses as you did.

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you have copy-pasted the code from a CHM / PDF file then be aware of the quotes. What appears as single / double quotes in the pdf is not treated as quotes in the text editor/shell etc.

type out the code on the py shell. it should work!

Comment: I did not copy on the pdf. I just type it here on my linux idle console but I can´t type the normal quotes

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the double quotes. Try to use a different word editor , it will surely solve the problem. 
For Linux , install gedit and then type the code and run it. 
For Mac, Install Text Wrangler and
For Windows , Install Notepad++.

This will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

The correct way to write a hello world is like this:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Mistakes you have done:
Space between print & bracket
No bracket is there

Comment: The OP was new to Python in 2012 so they've probably progressed since then... You might notice that the example shows the OP was using Python 2.6, so no brackets were necessary for print. The problem is the type of quote characters used, which was already mentioned by 5 other answers.

Comment: It's perfectly okay to have a space before the opening bracket.